# Oracle Apex page login region does not open with static id

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have created a login page (Based on default 'Login' template) and added a static content with following code.

```
<div class="sticky" >
   <div class="wrapper" id="stickyheader">
    <div class="box header">
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item button secondary"><a id="loginBtn" href="javascript:showLoginDialog();">Sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

after that I added 'showLoginDialog()' function in the page 'Function and Global Variable Declaration' as follows. I tried setting static id for the region ('loginDialog') but it didn't work. However, when I set the id (R71214435227774982) which is generated by apex page  works fine. But this workaround does not work when I deploy the same application on another environment as the generated id is changing when deploying. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

```
function showLoginDialog(){
    $("#R71214435227774982").show();   // Work fine.
   // $("#loginDialog").show();       //Doesn't work
}
```

[image: Screenshot of apex workspace with the login dialog element]

Comment: you haven't included elements with id `loginDialog` or `R71214435227774982` in your html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, the element with 'loginDialog' is set in the login region (static content) under the Static ID field. I added a screenshot for your easy reference.